# При place-content: center; Невозможно переместиться на элементы сверху и с лево

Tags: html, css

```html
<style>
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    html,
    body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    body {
        display: grid;
        place-content: center;
    }

    .container {
        width: 15vh;
        height: 15vh;
        display: inline-grid;
        grid-auto-rows: 100%;
        grid-auto-columns: 100%;
        grid-template-areas:
            "a b c d e"
            "f g h i j"
            "k l m n o"
            "p r s t u"
            "v w x y z";
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
        place-content: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }

    .block#one {
        grid-area: e;
        background: red;
    }

    .block#two {
        grid-area: h;
        background: green;
    }
</style>


<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="block" id="one"></div>
        <div class="block" id="two"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Как вы видите есть контейнер (который скрывает дочерние элементы и `place-content: center;`) внутри которого два элемента первый элемент красный а второй зелёный.
Проблема в том что я не могу перемещаться между зелёным и красным элементом, пример: `one.scrollIntoView()`. Перемещение до этого элемента не работает. Возможно ли без использований дополнительных элементов переместится к элементу one или two?

Буду рад если кто то сможет сделать это без дополнительных элементов и без Javascript кода.

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). в частности, информация о том, что у вас с чем-то там есть проблемы — это весьма мало-информативный заголовок.

Comment: я не придумал как назвать эту проблему если вы сможете помочь написать заголовок буду рад